# Test on @Transactional method fails:Concurrent update in table "WORK": another transaction has updated or deleted the same row

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

I have two entities and a service. Without @Transactional everything worked fine (except rollback). Now I added a @Transactional to the service method to make it an transaction and rollback automatically on errors. But  now all tests using this method fail with `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find org.kitodo.mediaserver.core.db.entities.Work with id xyz` (xyz is the ID of my Work item).

Then I tried to add `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` to the work field of ActionData entity. Than I get another exception on the same position as before: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Concurrent update in table "WORK": another transaction has updated or deleted the same row [90131-196]`

I assume for some reason it tries to use two transitions at the same time.

What's the reason and how can I make this work?

**The entities**

```
@Entity
public class Work {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String path;
    private String hostId;
    private Instant indexTime;
    private Set<Collection> collections;
    private String allowedNetwork = "global";

    protected Work() {}

    public Work(String id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "work_collection",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "work_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "collection_name", referencedColumnName = "name"))
    public Set<Collection> getCollections() {
        return collections;
    }

    // getters/setters

}


@Entity
public class ActionData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "action_parameter")
    private Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Work work;

    private String actionName;

    private Instant requestTime;
    private Instant startTime;
    private Instant endTime;

    private ActionData() {}

    public ActionData(Work work, String actionName, Map<String, String> parameter) {
        this.work = work;
        this.parameter = parameter;
        this.actionName = actionName;
    }

    // getters/setters

}
```

**The Service method**

```
@Service
public class ActionService {

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Object performRequested(ActionData actionData) throws Exception {

        // some checks

        actionData.setStartTime(Instant.now());

        // !!! javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find org.kitodo.mediaserver.core.db.entities.Work with id xyz
        actionRepository.save(actionData);

        IAction actionInstance = getActionInstance(actionData.getActionName());

        Object result;

        result = actionInstance.perform(actionData.getWork(), actionData.getParameter());

        actionData.setEndTime(Instant.now());
        actionRepository.save(actionData);

        return result;
    }
}
```

**The test**

```
@Test
public void performRequestedAction() throws Exception {

    // given
    init();
    work1 = entityManager.persist(work1);
    actionData1 = new ActionData(work1, "mockAction", parameter1);
    actionData1.setRequestTime(Instant.now());
    actionData1 = entityManager.persist(actionData1);
    entityManager.flush();

    // when
    Object action = actionService.performRequested(actionData1);

    // then
    assertThat(action).isNotNull();
    assertThat(action).isInstanceOf(String.class);
    assertThat(action).isEqualTo("performed");
    assertThat(actionData1.getStartTime()).isBetween(Instant.now().minusSeconds(2), Instant.now());
    assertThat(actionData1.getEndTime()).isBetween(Instant.now().minusSeconds(2), Instant.now());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, your Unittest is not working in autocommit mode.

The problem might be, that you don't commit the inserting-transaction in your testing function.

Therefore the saved data can not be seen by the called method actionService.performRequested() which starts a completely new transaction. This transaction will not be allowed to see any dirty data.
So either make sure that the data is saved either by setting autocommit-mode or committing the transaction which persists actionData1 in performRequestedAction.

Comment: Yes, I assume the problem is, that the test itself uses a transition. The DEBUG output says on every test it starts a transaction and rollbacks it after the test. It makes sense to keep a clean test DB. And this would be the cause, why my own transaction doesn't work. If I use auto-commit or no transaction in the test, I will break this clean DB. So I think this will cause other problems.

Comment: I agree, we always use Transactions to prepare testdata. In our case we can use in the testcode the UserTransaction for that. Alternatively you could check if you really need REQUIRES_NEW. In the default kind of propagation REQUIRED, the test should work. You must be aware, that the problems you have in coupling the testing-Transaction with the Method, you also can have, if you do local Service-Calls to the method. Normally the transaction should encapsulate complete business-transactions, not only parts of it.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround. There is a @Transactional on a class to ensure the Hibernate session stays open. I don't need a transaction there but this was the only way to make it work. This class calls the performRequested() which needs to run a transaction. So REQUIRES_NEW rolls back the current changes from performRequested() only. I assume I need a better solution for the Hibernate session to make this work as expected.

Comment: A hibernate-session means a DB-Connection. DB-Connection means  separate transactions. In J2EE-Container-talk I personally would rather talk in transaction-terms than in open hibernate-sessions. I personally would prefer to ignore hibernate completely (or as far as possible) and only use JPA and J2EE, even if the underlying OR-Mapping is implemented by hibernate.

Comment: OK, I understand the problem and the cause. I removed the workaround `@Transactional` and do a JOIN FETCH to get around the session problem. Now the real `@Transactional` does not need REQUIRES_NEW and the test works - everything works!